# html5 file exhibition on iphones cann't slide normallly

Tags: ios, objective-c, html, scrollview

My iOS app has some html5 pages. When you slide upper or down, then comes the question ,if you slide quickly , the page will block at some point, looks like the effect of the bounds property of scrollview,but just the opposite, it cann't show the full content on the page .only if you slide quiet slowly, then the other content on the page shows. It drives me crazy....

Comment: can you show your code. Can you apply the asynchronous concept or block concept.

Comment: the h5 code is no problem, because on Android and other devices it's OK. As to the asynchronous concept  I'm quiet sure how to apply.